# what ip will logged in a website if I access a website via another website through my PC?

Tags: domain, ip-address, web-crawler

If http://example2.com sends cURL connection to a website called http://example1.com. If I access http://example2.com from my pc to see the content of http://example1.com, than would http://example1.com will logged my PC's ip address or http://example2.com 's IP Address ?

In another word, if I'm visiting a website(A) from another website(B) (accessed via a computer(C)) than will the website I'm visiting(A) (by accessing another website(B)) log me as webhost ip address(ip of B) or my computer ip address(ip of C).

I'm very new at this, but What is the architecture behind it (how does it works)? Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'appear'?  Anyway if you are talking about a connection log, the answer is probably the IP of the machine that initiates the http/https connection, assuming no nat/proxies/vpns are changing things.

Comment: Does edit helps ? I feel you already answer the question, just trying to be sure.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but the best way to get a solid answer is to try it and see. Doing so will narrow your question, as this is very broad.

Comment: @spooler Well, I agree, It is kind of question 'One' will ask their professor, but I assume it can be answered it either option 1 or 2. 
Probably the purpose of stackExchange is to correcting someone's mistake rather than answering the question (I assume).  Thanks for you concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by accessed, **accessed via a computer(C)**

You are describing a proxy server for the most part.

If I RDP from my work computer ((C) Public IP 111.222.333.444) to my Home PC ((B) Public IP 222.333.444.555) and open up browser and hit google.com from my RDP session what google.com will see is my home IP 222.333.444.555.

The same would work If I ssh from my work computer ((C) Public IP 111.222.333.444) to my Home PC ((B) Public IP 222.333.444.555) and run a curl command and hit google.com from my ssh session what google.com will see is my home IP 222.333.444.555.

Comment: By access I meant exactly what you understood. LOL.

But does some same applies to http/https ?

Comment: Yes the same would apply to https, keep in mind this is at a very high level, there are tools that are run on certain sites that can and will track "accessed via IPs" so depending on what site you are trying to hack... I mean look at. You can and probably will get caught. The only other way would be to create multiple proxy servers and daisy chain them, using a service like digital ocean, you can spin up many servers for very cheap. Its one of the reason IPs are harder to track through service like TOR, many hops to get to one place. But we all know what happen saltroad.

Answer (score -2):

The remote host (website) will see your public IP (of your ISP).

Comment: Are you sure ? If I have a dedicated server and I had ISP-> Server -> Website, than website might see the server ip address than my ISP ip address ? isn't that right ?